# How to show only a substring of an item in a ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have some Company names as Items in a `ComboBox` like this:

`123 SomeCompany`

Always a number between 100 and 999 plus the company name.

Now if the user selects an Item I want the TextBox to only show the number, not the company name. he company name should only be visible when he drops down the ComboBox...

I tried to set `ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox.Text.Substring(0, 3)` in the SelectedIndexChanged-Event and the TextChanged-Event, but it didn't do anything, there was always everything in the ComboBox...

`AutocompleteMode` is set to `none`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try setting `SelectedText` ?

Comment: witch `TextBox` do you want to set?

Comment: i tried this: `ComboBox.selectionstart = 0` and i tried your suggestion earlier but it didn't do anything either...

Comment: Sry i made an error it's comobox not textbox....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To always format the value, you could use the Format event (with FormattingEnabled = true)

```
    private void comboBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    {   
          e.Value = e.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 3);
    }
```

But if you want the full value to be displayed when the dropdown is shown, you can temporarily disable the formatting:

```
    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = false;
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
textbox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().SubString(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private void combox1_ SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
      string value = (combox1.selectedItem != null) ? 
          combox1.selectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3) : string.Empty;
}
```