# How can I show only a part of a string in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Problem when files are being loaded in a combobox whose name starts the same way? I want to show only the first letter of the string that is separated by _

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSLl5.png)

```
private void frm_main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Meteo";

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {       
                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                comboBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
            }

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(path));
            }      
        }

        else

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Директорията Meteo не е октирта в системен диск 'C:\'");
            Application.ExitThread();
        }      
    }
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047688/how-to-show-only-a-substring-of-an-item-in-a-combobox-in-c-sharp work?

Comment: It would be clearer if you wrote in your question an example what the input is and what output you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want first letter `"0_2019_01_23.dat"` => `"0"` you may write:

```
var formattedName = Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_').First();
```

If your want to truncate `"0_2019_01_23.dat"` => `"23.dat"` you may write:

```
var formattedName = Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_').Last();
```

If you want to take various parts `"0_2019_01_23.dat"` => `"2019_01"` you may write:

```
var formattedName = string.Join("_", Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_').Skip(1).Take(2));
```

To change the order `"0_2019_01_23.dat"` => `"23_2019"` you may write:

```
var parts = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Split('_');
var formattedName = string.Join("_", new []{parts[3], parts[1]});
```